# Solving Cubic Equation using Cardano's method: $x^3-4x+1=0$

Tags: cubics

Substituting $x=u+v$, we get $$3uv=4$$ $$u^3+v^3=-1$$
and it follows that, $$u^3=-\frac{1}{2}+\iota \frac{\sqrt{687}}{18}$$
assume, $z=x+\iota y=-\frac{1}{2}+\iota \frac{\sqrt{687}}{18}$
$$r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$
$$r=\frac{8\sqrt{3}}{9}$$
$$\theta=\arctan(-\frac{\sqrt{687}}{9})$$
then the polar form is,
$$u^3=r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$$
$$u=r^{1/3}(\cos\frac{\theta+2k\pi}{3}+\iota \sin\frac{\theta+2k\pi}{3}) ,k=0,1,2$$ $$x=u+\frac{4}{3u}$$
$$u^3=r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$$
$$u=r^{1/3}(\cos\frac{\theta+2k\pi}{3}+\iota \sin\frac{\theta+2k\pi}{3}) k=0,1,2 $$ $$x=u+\frac{4}{3u}$$
We can get three solutions of x using k=0,1,2.
But this method does not result in correct solutions. Any idea why?
Another way I tried,
$$v=r^{1/3}(\cos\frac{\theta+2k\pi}{3}-\iota \sin\frac{\theta+2k\pi}{3}) ,k=0,1,2$$
$$x=u+v$$
$$x=2r^{1/3}(\cos\frac{\theta+2k\pi}{3})$$
This method results in correct solutions for x when k=0,1,2 is used, but sign is opposite, which I guess can be fixed when taking signed values of the roots?. Will this method work for all irreducible cases?